# Entering unicode through EditText

Tags: android, button, unicode, android-edittext

I have a TextWatcher on an EditText box. 
When the user types I set whatever is on the EditText Box as a Button label.

```
EditText et = rootView.findViewById(R.id.userInput);
et.addTextChangedListener(this);
...

@Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
@Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    Button btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    btn.setText(s.toString());
    //btn.setText("\u00A9");
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to write **unicode symbols**. The commented line, when uncommented, sets the `Button` text to the copyright symbol © . Though entering the same unicode code in the EditText box does not work. 
I tried to type double backslash in the EditText, still not good.

Note: unrelated to this, when using `btn.setText(s)` without the `toString()` part, the text in the button is underlined.

**CLARIFICATION**
Due to some comments and answers (now deleted) I realize that I was not clear. Let me rephrase:

I don't want to interfere with the user input text in any way. Right now when the user inputs **"Hello \u0089"** in the EditText, I copy it to the Button text using this line:

```
btn.setText(s.toString());
```

and it shows as **"Hello \u0089"**. I expected **"Hello ‰"**. Why? because if I run a little test and use this line:

```
btn.setText("Hello \u0089");
```

it shows as **"Hello ‰"**. So, what is the difference that makes the unicode to show properly in the direct approach but does not show it when is entered through EditText?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want the user to enter the code and then change the code to its respective symbol on the fly?

Comment: @shoerat Sorry for the unclearness. I don't want to interfere at all with the user input. I am saying that when the user enters a unicode code like \u2303 it is not displayed as unicode. I will add a clarification on the question itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, what is the difference that makes the unicode to show properly in the direct approach but does not show it when is entered through EditText?

Arggh, I want people to stop saying "the unicode". It's "the text", not "the unicode". Unicode is a standard. The text the user entered is not that one standard, it's just text.

With that out of the way, let's see if I can explain the difference.

When you write a string literal like `"Hello \u0089"` in Java, your source code file will contain the following sequence of characters:

1. a [U+0022 ǫᴜᴏᴛᴀᴛɪᴏɴ ᴍᴀʀᴋ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm);
2. a [U+0048 ʟᴀᴛɪɴ ᴄᴀᴘɪᴛᴀʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ʜ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0048/index.htm);
3. a [U+0065 ʟᴀᴛɪɴ sᴍᴀʟʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ᴇ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0065/index.htm);
4. a [U+006C ʟᴀᴛɪɴ sᴍᴀʟʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ʟ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/006C/index.htm);
5. a [U+006C ʟᴀᴛɪɴ sᴍᴀʟʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ʟ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/006C/index.htm);
6. a [U+006F ʟᴀᴛɪɴ sᴍᴀʟʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ᴏ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/006F/index.htm);
7. a [U+0020 sᴘᴀᴄᴇ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm);
8. a [U+005C ʀᴇᴠᴇʀsᴇ sᴏʟɪᴅᴜs](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/005c/index.htm) (also known as a backslash);
9. a [U+0075 ʟᴀᴛɪɴ sᴍᴀʟʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ᴜ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0075/index.htm);
10. a [U+0030 ᴅɪɢɪᴛ ᴢᴇʀᴏ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0030/index.htm);
11. a [U+0030 ᴅɪɢɪᴛ ᴢᴇʀᴏ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0030/index.htm);
12. a [U+0038 ᴅɪɢɪᴛ ᴇɪɢʜᴛ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0038/index.htm);
13. a [U+0039 ᴅɪɢɪᴛ ɴɪɴᴇ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0039/index.htm); and
14. a [U+0022 ǫᴜᴏᴛᴀᴛɪᴏɴ ᴍᴀʀᴋ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm).

There is no magic involved here. What you type is what you get. The `\u0089` sequence is not magical.

However, when you give that same source file to your Java compiler, the Java compiler has an agreement with you, the programmer: it will convert any sequence it finds inside a string literal that starts with the characters U+005C U+0075 and is followed by four hexadecimal digit characters into the character that corresponds to the Unicode value specified by those hexadecimal digits. That agreement also includes a provision for when you, the programmer, want to actually meant that sequence with the backslash, the u, and the hexadecimal digits, i.e., six characters, not one. For that you precede the backslash with another backslash, and the Java compiler doesn't perform any other transformation besides removing one of those two backslashes.

So, while the source file will have the string literal with twelve characters between quotation marks, the Java compiler will, following the agreement with the programmer set forth by the Java Specificiation, transform that into a string with only seven characters.

1. a [U+0048 ʟᴀᴛɪɴ ᴄᴀᴘɪᴛᴀʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ʜ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0048/index.htm);
2. a [U+0065 ʟᴀᴛɪɴ sᴍᴀʟʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ᴇ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0065/index.htm);
3. a [U+006C ʟᴀᴛɪɴ sᴍᴀʟʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ʟ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/006C/index.htm);
4. a [U+006C ʟᴀᴛɪɴ sᴍᴀʟʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ʟ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/006C/index.htm);
5. a [U+006F ʟᴀᴛɪɴ sᴍᴀʟʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ᴏ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/006F/index.htm);
6. a [U+0020 sᴘᴀᴄᴇ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm);
7. a [U+0089 ᴄʜᴀʀᴀᴄᴛᴇʀ ᴛᴀʙᴜʟᴀᴛɪᴏɴ ᴡɪᴛʜ ᴊᴜsᴛɪғɪᴄᴀᴛɪᴏɴ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0089/index.htm);

Now, when the user is entering text into some UI, they are not typing in Java string literals that will later be processed by the Java compiler, or are they?

They are not. When the user types a backslash followed by a u and some digits, the user gets a backslash followed by a u and some digits. When the user inputs `\u0089` in a text field, that text field holds a string with six characters, not one. There is no Java compiler there with any pre-agreed convention to represent characters by their Unicode values; it's just a user entering text, not Java code.

When the user inputs `\u0089` in a text field, the text fields holds a string that can be represented *in Java source code* as `"\\u0089"`, not `"\u0089"`.

If you want to give to that kind of user input the same meaning that the Java compiler gives to those Unicode escape sequences, you need to call code that does such a transformation before displaying it.

**FOR COMPLETENESS**
This is the OP posting code I wrote based on the answer above.

```
public static String convertUnicode(CharSequence s) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\\\u([0-9a-zA-Z]{4,4})\\b").matcher(s);
    while ( m.find() ) {
        char c = (char) Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16);
        m.appendReplacement(result, String.valueOf(c) );
    }
    m.appendTail(result);
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the detailed description! It was illuminating. And the answer is...??? What is that famous code "that does such transformation"? Has to be done char by char or is there a built in function that does the conversion?

Comment: I am accepting your answer, though it lacks the conversion code sample, because I see you invested time in writing it and was very helpful. Feel free, anyway, to edit it with some lines of code that may do the trick, for completeness.

Comment: You might also look into `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(String str)`.  It does a similar thing as that last block of code, but with respect to the other other escape sequences, as well.